# how to make nested object validation in japi joi

Tags: javascript, typescript, hapi.js, joi

### joi  validated  with nested object

### Thanks in advance Please help if any one can

### i have try this but not achive nested validation

```
var nestedSchema = Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
           title: Joi.string(),
           type: Joi.string().valid(["postback", "web_url","nested"]).required(),
            url: Joi.string(),
            payload: Joi.string(),
{
                locale: Joi.string(),
                composerInputDisabled: Joi.boolean().valid([true, false]).required(),
                call_to_actions: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
                    title: Joi.string(),
                    type: Joi.string().valid(["postback", "web_url", "nested"]).required(),
                    url: Joi.string(),
                    payload: Joi.string(),
                    call_to_actions: Joi.array().when('type', {
                        is: 'nested', then: nestedSchema
                    }).concat(Joi.array().when('type', {
                        is: 'nested', then: nestedSchema
                    })).concat(Joi.array().when('type', {
                        is: 'nested', then: nestedSchema
                    }))
                }))
            }?
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what do you need exactly?

Answer (score -2):

You can take a look a this page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema
It think it should solve your problem

Comment: It won't solve any problem, the question about Joi, and it is perfectly capable of many complex validation schemas. Please consider the context while answering.